# Kubernetes Job Output metrics to Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I want to create a Kubernetes Job object like the example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/

Now imagine I want to have the result (in this case the value of Pi: `3.14159...`) available in Prometheus.

Is this possible?

In a more complex example, imagine the output of my pod was JSON:

```
{
  "foo": 200,
  "bar": 10,
  "baz": 999
}
```

I somehow need to denote that I'm interested in `foo` and `baz` "being available" in Prom (note I'm not opinionated on whether the solution is `push` or `pull`.

### Option 1

The first option I've thought of is somehow attaching the result `3.14159` to the job and Prom can scrape it as normal.

### Option 2

Don't run the Pi-generator container at all, instead run something like a Python script that runs the Pi process. Then we can push from Python to Prom.

### Option 3

Some other way?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but metrics collection via prometheus, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Closed in favour of this post at DevOps: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/16408/kubernetes-job-metrics-in-prometheus